# Why can't an `Import[]` change $Path?

Tags: import

Does anyone know why `Import["http://**server**/file.m"]` can't make a change to `$Path`? It seems like `file.m` can set pretty much any other variable, but not `$Path`.

I suspect `Get[]` would work, but I can't seem to get `Get[]` to fetch files over the web.

Comment: Possibly a security measure?

Comment: I'm creating and deleting files and directories in my `Import`ed file, so if it's a security measure it's impressively poorly designed. It feels more like there's some "specialness" to the context that the Import is being evaluated in.

Comment: In V9, we made Get take an InputStream, which can be opened from a URL. In http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Get.html, and where it says "Updated in 9" in the upper right, click "Show changes".

Comment: Actually, in V9, Get from a URL string should just work, you don't need to explicitly open a stream.

Answer (score 7):

I think \$Path is probably being set in a Block in the Import call.  I put this sample code on a server in test.m:

```
beforePath = $Path;
    AppendTo[$Path, "d:/tomcat-6.0.35"];
afterPath = $Path;
DateString[]
```

I can see that afterPath has the correct value, but $Path is unmodified.

```
In[14]:= Import["http://jfkleinlx.wri.wolfram.com/test.m"]

Out[14]= "Thu 17 Jan 2013 09:58:52"

In[19]:= Complement[afterPath, beforePath]

Out[19]= {"d:/tomcat-6.0.35"}

In[20]:= $Path === beforePath

Out[20]= True
```

With V9, to work around this you can open a stream to a URL and use Get as you suspected:

```
In[21]:= st = OpenRead["http://jfkleinlx.wri.wolfram.com/test.m"]

Out[21]= InputStream["http://jfkleinlx.wri.wolfram.com/test.m", 133]

In[22]:= Get[st]

Out[22]= "Thu 17 Jan 2013 10:06:11"

In[24]:= $Path === afterPath

Out[24]= True
```

Remember to Close the stream.  Or, you can just Get the URL directly: Get["http://jfkleinlx.wri.wolfram.com/test.m"], which opens a stream internally.

Comment: That is a lame `test.m`. You should instead replace the contents with `SystemOpen["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"]`  :D

Comment: That's a good point, here's a stopgap if you are working without Internet: `Speak[Uncompress[  "1:eJxVjcENAjEMBFPK0sCVwgMq8BErRAT75IsPpS8KJArwyMPSamc1Pq16ub5DCGc+2JA0S0JVpHwwmjp8W/BnIoTCdfRRXzITcwGZukRQv8g729jOsyc9vuabtZns1HrSuDaeQeVS0F9nHua7/7wfYipCUA=="]]`

Comment: There's no way to ninja out of a block, right?